# Get avareage of n previous months by month query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm making a a query that gets the count of 2 columns and sum of another column, grouping by month from a date column of the last 13 months. This is my query :

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM') as month ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AS col1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT col2) as col2,
        SUM(col3) as col3 
FROM myTable
WHERE TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM') IN (select distinct TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM')
                                     from myTable
                                     order by  1 desc
                                     limit 13)
GROUP BY 1
```

The problem is that for each month, I also need the average of the previous 3 months of the :

COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AS col1,
COUNT(DISTINCT col2) as col2,
SUM(col3) as col3

so my query need to be something like :

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM') as month ,
            COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AS col1,
            COUNT(DISTINCT col2) as col2,
            SUM(col3) as col3,
            ... as PreviousMonthsAvgCol1,
            ... as PreviousMonthsAvgCol2,
            ... as PreviousMonthsAvgCol3
    FROM myTable
    WHERE TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM') IN (select distinct TO_CHAR(colDate,'yyyy_MM')
                                         from myTable
                                         order by  1 desc
                                         limit 13)
    GROUP BY 1
```

The months before the first still need to be counted in the average of the first month.

Comment: What about the first month in your result set?

Comment: Not certain if you are using MS SQL Server, but have you considered creating a UDF (User Defined Function) to accept parameters to calculate averages for a specific time span?  For larger data sets, this may present performance lags, but it may be worth considering.

Comment: The months before the first need to be counted in the average.

Comment: I think I will make my query get 16 months and calculate everyhting in my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need data from before the 13 month period, just use `lag()`:

```
SELECT . . .,
       LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT col1)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(colDate)) as prev_col1,
   . . . 
FROM myTable . . .;
```

If you do need earlier data, then do the full aggregation *and then* choose the 13 months.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, with Gordon Lindoff's answer.

However, I recommend not using `TO_CHAR()` in the date range predicate. This will force Redshift to scan more data than necessary.

Try using `colDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2018-01-31'` or `DATE_TRUNC()` if you *must* round the dates to whole months.